# Boto3 Adding an Inbound Rule to a Security Group in a Non Default VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-security-group

I am trying to add an inbound rule to a security group in a non default VPC.  I am using this code:

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

def modify_sg_add_rules():
        response = ec2.authorize_security_group_ingress(
        IpPermissions=
        [
            { 
                'FromPort': 3306,
                'IpProtocol': 'tcp',
                'IpRanges': 
                    [
                        {
                        'CidrIp': '64.192.85.294/32',
                        'Description': 'My home IP',
                        },
                    ],
                'ToPort': 3306,
                'UserIdGroupPairs': 
                    [
                        {
                            'Description': 'My home IP',
                            'GroupId': 'sg-0123',
                            # 'GroupName': 'mysql-sg-0123',
                            'VpcId': 'vpc-0f93q3',
                        },
                    ]
            },
        ],
    )
```

However, I am getting the following error:

*botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (MissingParameter) when calling the AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress operation: The request must contain the parameter groupName or groupId*

I have tried it including the group name, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with security group id it works:

```
data = client_ec2.authorize_security_group_ingress(
        GroupId='sg-01b8f7d6ae1022a20',
        IpPermissions=[
            {'IpProtocol': 'tcp',
             'FromPort': 80,
             'ToPort': 80,
             'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': '0.0.0.0/0'}]},
            {'IpProtocol': 'tcp',
             'FromPort': 22,
             'ToPort': 22,
             'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': '0.0.0.0/0'}]}
        ])
print('Ingress Successfully Set %s' % data)
```

Output:

```
Ingress Successfully Set {'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': xxxx, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': ......}}
```

It should be possible to get the security group id also programatically - filtering by security group name.

Comment: Hello Encho: Yes! It works! I had to tweak my code a little bit after following your suggestion.